Connecting two wires to one breaker
I have two light circuits that share a neutral. The lights are now all LED, so each circuit draws about 2 amps. Can I run both wires from one breaker? I need to free up a breaker for another use.

That only works if the fixtures have been converted to types which reject incandescent bulbs, such as LED/CFL only sockets (GU24) or bulbless LEDs.  If you're keeping your Edison screw-bases and thus the option to rollback to incandescent, then you must keep the provisioning to those bulbs. E.G. a 3-bulb fixture labeled "60W max bulb" must be allocated 180W.

If each one is actually drawing 2A with LEDs then, as Harper pointed out, you have an issue because some later owner will decide to screw in their stash of actual-60W bulbs, unless you have converted to integral-LED fixtures where that isn't possible. 2A = 240W is a lot of LED lighting. But in any case, there are likely plenty of other things that can be done in your panel besides changing this one MWBC. Picture of your panel would help.

Have fixtures been replaced or are you just using low watt bulbs? What is the sum of fixture labeling? "NEC 220.14 (D) Luminaires. An outlet supplying a luminaire(s) shall be calculated based on the maximum volt-ampere rating of the equipment and lamps for which the luminaire(s) is rated."

No, you cannot run both wires from a single breaker. Then you would have a circuit masquerading as a MWBC when in reality it is not. That can seriously mislead the next person working on the circuit in their determination of what additional loads the circuit could handle.
What you can do is disconnect and cap-off one wire (preferably red). Then change everything that used to be connected to the red leg of the MWBC over to the black wire.
That way, you convert a MWBC to a regular circuit that happens to have an unused red wire in the cables.

Please explain why it cannot be done. Nothing the OP said suggests the combined loads of the formerly separate circuits would exceed the capacity of the single neutral. Incandescent lighting circuits rarely even approach the maximum capacity of the wires used, and the conversion to LED fixtures likely (but not necessarily, as pointed out in comments) dramatically reduced the loading.
